# How to pass conditional check if item does not exist with UpdateItem request in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to run an UpdateItem request against Amazon DynamoDB with an condition that will always succeed if the item does not yet exist. For example:

```
long timestampNow = System.currentTimeMillis();

UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
        .withPrimaryKey("primary_key", theKey)
        .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW)
        .withAttributeUpdate(
                new AttributeUpdate("my_attr").put(timestampNow+SOME_DURATION))
        .withExpected(
                new Expected("my_attr").lt(timestampNow)); 
try {
    UpdateItemOutcome outcome = AWS.DYNAMO_DOC.getTable("my_table").updateItem(updateItemSpec);
    return outcome.getUpdateItemResult().getAttributes();

} catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException e) {
    return null;
}
```

When I make requests for items that don't exist yet, it throws `ConditionalCheckFailedException`, but I'd like it pass the condition test and just go ahead and create the item. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The docs actually have everything I needed to know:

```
long timestampNow = System.currentTimeMillis();

UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
        .withPrimaryKey("primary_key", theKey)
        .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW)
        .withConditionExpression("attribute_not_exists(my_attr) or my_attr < :now")
        .withUpdateExpression("SET my_attr = :exp")
        .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                .withLong(":now", timestampNow)
                .withLong(":exp", timestampNow+LOCK_EXPIRY_DURATION));
try {
    UpdateItemOutcome outcome = AWS.DYNAMO_DOC.getTable("my_table").updateItem(updateItemSpec);
    return outcome.getUpdateItemResult().getAttributes();

} catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException e) {
    return null;
}
```